# JUnit "fail" method is not printing to console

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, automated-tests

I'm writing a very simple JUnit test and realized that my failure messages don't seem to be printed at all. The test does fail, but there is no output. Where does `fail` print to?

```
@Test
public void testSimpleMethod() {
    fail("Test failed!");
}
```

If `fail` doesn't print the message you give it, what is the point of giving it a message in the first place?

Comment: **More info:** `System.out.println()` does print to the console as expected.

Comment: Per the code, it throws an AssertionError with the message provided. This is handled per junit. How are you running tests? If I run your test via maven or eclipse's junit plugin, I can see the message.

Comment: While I agree that this is strange, I haven't used `fail` in any of my tests.  Normally I let the expectations fail or let an exception bubble up instead of being explicit about "fail".

Comment: Where are you running this?

Comment: I'm running this in eclipse in a maven project using java 8

Comment: Yeah, so open the JUnit view and it'll be under Failure Trace.

Comment: Ahh, it is showing up under "Failure Trace" and I can see the message there. At least that's one way to find it.

Comment: If you run a maven command line build ("mvn test" in a console window) does it appear there? You'll probably find the output in a file under 'target/surefire-reports'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered in the comments, so I am posting an official answer here:

The failure message can be viewed in the JUnit view under "Failure Trace".